# I can't print the mean value of survfit(...)

Tags: r

I used the data, aml in survival package in R and computed a survival function by
"survfit". Since the result of survfit doesn't show the mean value,
I used the following code to print the mean:

```
> print(survfit(Surv(aml1$time,aml1$status)~1),show.rmean=T)
```

(the data I used is, `aml1 <-aml[aml$x="Maintained",]`)

The code above worked in my friend pc, but not mine.
So, I thought about downloading  some extra package to use `print(...show.rmean=T)`.
But, "print" is basic, so I don't need anything to run  print.
Then why I can't get the mean value?

Comment: Update your package survival... it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

`print` is a generic function, with options that may be specific to the thing it's printing.  In this case, options are provided by `print.survfit`.  Although my version of `survival` actually doesn't have a `show.rmean`. Perhaps you want `print.rmean`?  See the help for `print.survfit` for more information.

```
> print(survfit(Surv(aml1$time,aml1$status)~1), print.rmean=T)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(aml1$time, aml1$status) ~ 1)

   records      n.max    n.start     events     *rmean *se(rmean)     median 
     23.00      23.00      23.00      18.00      36.36       9.85      27.00 
   0.95LCL    0.95UCL 
     18.00      45.00 
    * restricted mean with upper limit =  161
```